# How to list files and folder in a dir (PHP)

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to show all files and folders in a dir with php

e.g

Dir: **system/infomation/**

**Folder** - User

**Files From User** - User1.txt

**Files From User** - User2.txt

**Files From User** - User3.txt

**Files From User** - User4.txt

Folder - **Players**

**Files From Players** - Player1.txt

**Files From Players** - Player2.txt

**Files From Players** - Player3.txt

**Files From Players** - Player4.txt

Can someone lead me down the right street please

Thank You

Comment: [please use the search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=recursive+directory+php) before asking duplicate questions.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

PHP 5 has the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php).

The manual has a basic example:

```
<?php

$directory = '/system/infomation/';

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));

while($it->valid()) {

    if (!$it->isDot()) {

        echo 'SubPathName: ' . $it->getSubPathName() . "\n";
        echo 'SubPath:     ' . $it->getSubPath() . "\n";
        echo 'Key:         ' . $it->key() . "\n\n";
    }

    $it->next();
}

?>
```

---

**Edit** --  Here's a slightly more advanced example (only slightly) which produces output similar to what you want (i.e. folder names then files).

```
// Create recursive dir iterator which skips dot folders
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./system/information',
    FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

// Flatten the recursive iterator, folders come before their files
$it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

// Maximum depth is 1 level deeper than the base folder
$it->setMaxDepth(1);

// Basic loop displaying different messages based on file or folder
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
        printf("Folder - %s\n", $fileinfo->getFilename());
    } elseif ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        printf("File From %s - %s\n", $it->getSubPath(), $fileinfo->getFilename());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for making answer to an obvious duplicate a CW

Comment: Would there be any chance you can make it so all the files that belongs to that folder will list under that one folder name?

Comment: @Gully yes, using `basename()` and `dirname()`

Comment: @Gully see the 2nd example code snippet

Comment: Using the second code snippet gives me an error.  Something about too many open files.  Is this a server setting issue?

Comment: is it possible to get the file create/modification date also?

Answer (score 29):

```
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "../data/team/";

//get all text files with a .txt extension.
$texts = glob($directory . "*.txt");

//print each file name
foreach($texts as $text)
{
    echo $text;
}
```

Comment: Good point for that check if the file is a `.txt`. Despite the question was not asking for `*.txt` files, here comes an upvote.

Comment: @Korcholis The examples in the question are only for `.txt` files. Also it is obvious that this will also work by replacing `.txt` with any other extension you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
 foreach (new DirectoryIterator("./system/information/") as $fn) {
     print $fn->getFilename();
 }
```

You'll have to use it twice for each subdir, Players and User.

Answer (score 4):

**LIST FILES IN FOLDER - 1 solution**

```
<?php 
// open this directory 
$myDirectory = opendir(".");
// get each entry
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}
// close directory
closedir($myDirectory);
//  count elements in array
$indexCount = count($dirArray);
Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n");
// sort 'em
sort($dirArray);
// print 'em
print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks>\n");
print("<TR><TH>Filename</TH><th>Filetype</th><th>Filesize</th></TR>\n");
// loop through the array of files and print them all
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ // don't list hidden files
        print("<TR><TD><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
        print("<td>");  print(filetype($dirArray[$index])); print("</td>");
        print("<td>");  print(filesize($dirArray[$index])); print("</td>");
        print("</TR>\n");
    }
}
print("</TABLE>\n");
?>
```

**2 solution**

```
<?PHP
# The current directory
$directory = dir("./");

# If you want to turn on Extension Filter, then uncomment this:
### $allowed_ext = array(".sample", ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".txt", ".doc", ".xls"); 




## Description of the soft: list_dir_files.php  
## Major credits: phpDIRList 2.0 -(c)2005 Ulrich S. Kapp :: Systemberatung ::

$do_link = TRUE; 
$sort_what = 0; //0- by name; 1 - by size; 2 - by date
$sort_how = 0; //0 - ASCENDING; 1 - DESCENDING


# # #
function dir_list($dir){ 
    $i=0; 
    $dl = array(); 
    if ($hd = opendir($dir))    { 
        while ($sz = readdir($hd)) {  
            if (preg_match("/^\./",$sz)==0) $dl[] = $sz;$i.=1;  
        } 
    closedir($hd); 
    } 
    asort($dl); 
    return $dl; 
} 
if ($sort_how == 0) { 
    function compare0($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[0] == $y[0] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[0] < $y[0] ) return -1;  
        else return 1;  
    }  
    function compare1($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[1] == $y[1] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[1] < $y[1] ) return -1;  
        else return 1;  
    }  
    function compare2($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[2] == $y[2] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[2] < $y[2] ) return -1;  
        else return 1;  
    }  
}else{ 
    function compare0($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[0] == $y[0] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[0] < $y[0] ) return 1;  
        else return -1;  
    }  
    function compare1($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[1] == $y[1] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[1] < $y[1] ) return 1;  
        else return -1;  
    }  
    function compare2($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[2] == $y[2] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[2] < $y[2] ) return 1;  
        else return -1;  
    }  

} 

################################################## 
#    We get the information here 
################################################## 

$i = 0; 
while($file=$directory->read()) { 
    $file = strtolower($file);
    $ext = strrchr($file, '.');
    if (isset($allowed_ext) && (!in_array($ext,$allowed_ext)))
        {
            // dump 
        }
    else { 
        $temp_info = stat($file); 
        $new_array[$i][0] = $file; 
        $new_array[$i][1] = $temp_info[7]; 
        $new_array[$i][2] = $temp_info[9]; 
        $new_array[$i][3] = date("F d, Y", $new_array[$i][2]); 
        $i = $i + 1; 
        } 
} 
$directory->close(); 

################################################## 
# We sort the information here 
################################################# 

switch ($sort_what) { 
    case 0: 
            usort($new_array, "compare0"); 
    break; 
    case 1: 
            usort($new_array, "compare1"); 
    break; 
    case 2: 
            usort($new_array, "compare2"); 
    break; 
} 

############################################################### 
#    We display the infomation here 
############################################################### 

$i2 = count($new_array); 
$i = 0; 
echo "<table border=1> 
                <tr> 
                    <td width=150> File name</td> 
                    <td width=100> File Size</td> 
                    <td width=100>Last Modified</td> 
                </tr>"; 
for ($i=0;$i<$i2;$i++) { 
    if (!$do_link) { 
        $line = "<tr><td align=right>" .  
                        $new_array[$i][0] .  
                        "</td><td align=right>" .  
                        number_format(($new_array[$i][1]/1024)) .  
                        "k"; 
        $line = $line  . "</td><td align=right>" . $new_array[$i][3] . "</td></tr>"; 
    }else{ 
        $line = '<tr><td align=right><A HREF="' .   
                        $new_array[$i][0] . '">' .  
                        $new_array[$i][0] .  
                        "</A></td><td align=right>"; 
        $line = $line . number_format(($new_array[$i][1]/1024)) .  
                        "k"  . "</td><td align=right>" .  
                        $new_array[$i][3] . "</td></tr>"; 
    } 
    echo $line; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 


?>
```

Comment: Why doesn't solution #1 list any files besides .php files?

Answer (score 2):

You may use Directory Functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dir.php

Simple example from [opendir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) function description:

```
<?php
$dir_path = "/path/to/your/dir";

if (is_dir($dir_path)) {
    if ($dir_handler = opendir($dir_path)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dir_handler)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir_path . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dir_handler);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

use this function http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=71882

```
function getDirectory( $path = '.', $level = 0 ){

$ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..' ); 
// Directories to ignore when listing output. Many hosts 
// will deny PHP access to the cgi-bin. 

$dh = @opendir( $path ); 
// Open the directory to the handle $dh 

while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ){ 
// Loop through the directory 

    if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) ){ 
    // Check that this file is not to be ignored 

        $spaces = str_repeat( '&nbsp;', ( $level * 4 ) ); 
        // Just to add spacing to the list, to better 
        // show the directory tree. 

        if( is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){ 
        // Its a directory, so we need to keep reading down... 

            echo "<strong>$spaces $file</strong><br />"; 
            getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) ); 
            // Re-call this same function but on a new directory. 
            // this is what makes function recursive. 

        } else { 

            echo "$spaces $file<br />"; 
            // Just print out the filename 

        } 

    } 

} 

closedir( $dh ); 
// Close the directory handle 
}
```

and call the function like that

```
getDirectory( "." ); 
// Get the current directory 

getDirectory( "./files/includes" ); 
// Get contents of the "files/includes" folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Use glob. There are comprehensive guide how to open all files from dir:
[PHP: Using functional programming for listing files and directories](http://domexception.blogspot.fi/2013/08/php-using-functional-programming-for.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Dir class or `opendir()` and `readdir()` in a recursive function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php

http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Answer (score 0):

I've found in www.laughing-buddha.net/php/lib/dirlist/ a function that returns an array containing a list of a directory's contents.

Also look at php.net http://es.php.net/manual/es/ref.filesystem.php where you'll find additional functions for working with files in php.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [building a simple directory browser using php RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223365/building-a-simple-directory-browser-using-php-recursivedirectoryiterator)

Also, as you mentioned you want to list you can also look at some ready made libraries that create file/folder explorers e.g.:

- http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with accessing to the path, maybe you need to put this:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path = "/cv/"; 

// Open the folder
 $dir_handle = @opendir($root . $path) or die("Unable to open $path");
```