# How do I list all the contents of a directory?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to make an index.html file which links all the files in a directory in an ordered list.

For example, when you go [here](http://searchr.us/web-search/), you find:

```
# Parent Directory
# &lt;u&gt;lol.html
# &quot;&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert(String.fromCharCode(72)-String.fromCharCode(105)).html
# -AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATESTING.html
# 0dl.blogspot.com.html
# 1000-suns.html
# 123-greeting.html
# 151.html
# 1^2+2-.-2^2-+-3^2-+2-.-4^2.html
# 2010-IIT-JEE-Solutions-Fiitjee.html
# 2010-IIT-JEE-Solutions.html
```

**What I want to do:**

```
<a href="http://searchr.us/web-search/&lt%3bu&gt%3blol.html" >&lt;u&gt;lol.html</a>
<a href="http://searchr.us/web-search/&quot%3b&gt%3b&lt%3bscript&gt%3balert(String.fromCharCode(72)-String.fromCharCode(105)).html">http://searchr.us/web-search/&quot%3b&gt%3b&lt%3bscript&gt%3balert(String.fromCharCode(72)-String.fromCharCode(105)).html</a>
```

And so on...

Comment: Maybe I'm seeing the wrong thing, but at that link there is already an unordered list of hyperlinks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list files and folder in a dir (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050511/how-to-list-files-and-folder-in-a-dir-php)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$dir = getcwd();

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'/'.$file.'">' . $file . '</a><br />';
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

Be carefull the href value of the a tag must be changed this is only an example to get you started .

Comment: make sure you escape any special characters in those filenames with `htmlspecialchars()`...

Comment: Not able to understand mate :(

Answer (score 1):

[How to list files from a directory with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050511/how-to-list-files-and-folder-in-a-dir-php) [has been answered way too often](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=recursive+directory+php) to answer it here again. However, the listing at that links looks a lot like Apache's built-in directory indexes, which you can enable by putting

```
Options +Indexes
```

in an `.htaccess` file in that folder. See the following links

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enabling-apache-file-directory-indexing/
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html