# How to get image names from all sub directories?

Tags: php

I have used following php code to get all images names from relevant directory.

```
$dir = "images";
$images = scandir($dir);
$listImages=array();
foreach($images as $image){
    $listImages=$image;
    echo ($listImages) ."<br>";
}
```

This one works perfectly. But I want to get all images file names within all sub directories from relevant directory. Parent directory does not contain images and all the images contain in sub folders as folows.

- Parent Dir

  - Sub Dir

    - image1
    - image2
  - Sub Dir2

    - image3
    - image4

How I go through the all sub folders and get the images names?

Comment: u have to use a function that calls itself. just check if Directory is empty. if not take subdirectory and use function within. this way it Loops through all Directorys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [building a simple directory browser using php RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223365/building-a-simple-directory-browser-using-php-recursivedirectoryiterator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following. To get full directory path, merge with parent directory.

```
$path = 'images'; // '.' for current
   foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file) {
   if ($file->isDot()) continue;

   if ($file->isDir()) {
       $dir = $path.'/'. $file->getFilename();

   $images = scandir($dir);
       $listImages=array();
       foreach($images as $image){
           $listImages=$image;
           echo ($listImages) ."<br>";
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing recursion, you can make this quite easily. This function will indefinitely go through your directories until each directory is done searching. THIS WAS NOT TESTED.

```php
$images = [];

function getImages(&$images, $directory) {
    $files = scandir($directory); // you should get rid of . and .. too

    foreach($files as $file) {
        if(is_dir($file) {
            getImages($images, $directory . '/' . $file);
        } else {
            array_push($images, $file); /// you may also check if it is indeed an image
        }
    }
}

getImages($images, 'images');
```