# Read html files on directory tree through php and insert to mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql, regex, dom

I have a folder structure like this example

```
Groups 
- apple
-- ahen45.html
-- rev34.html
-- ......

- bat
-- fsf.html
-- ere.html
--....

...
```

Groups is parent folded. apple,bat etc sub folders

like this more than 500 hundred sub folders and more than 20000 html files there. Now im trying to read those html file through php and separate **title** , **meta keywords**, **body** and the sub folder as **category**.

```
<?php
$file =$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('groups/',
    FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

$it->setMaxDepth(1);

foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
       echo $category = $fileinfo->getFilename();

    }
    else if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        $fileinfo->getFilename();
        $myURL = $file.'/group/groups/'.$category.'/'.$fileinfo->getFilename();

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTMLFile($myURL);

        $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
        $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
        $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body'); 

    foreach ($elements as $el) {
            echo $el->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    }

    }
}
?>
```

When I try like this it is checking whole page and give warning like tag(other tags like or ) is unclosed. what can I do to work perfectly?

Comment: So what have you tried to this point? What problems are you having?  or are you just wanting someone to do this for you?

Comment: Yes I need a solution to this, I dont have any idea about it

Comment: Well then you have come to the wrong place.  It is expected here that you at least put forth some effort to solve the problem yourself before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$file =$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('groups/',
    FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

$it->setMaxDepth(1);

foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
       echo $category = $fileinfo->getFilename();      
    }
    else if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        $fileinfo->getFilename();
        $myURL = $file.'/group/groups/'.$category.'/'.$fileinfo->getFilename();


        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTMLFile($myURL);
        $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
        $doc->recover=true;
        $doc->formatOutput = true;

        $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');        
        $elements1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
        $elements2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');

            for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
            {
                $meta = $metas->item($i);
                if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords'){
                    echo $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
                    echo "<br/>";
                }
            }

            foreach ($elements1 as $el1) {
                echo $el1->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
                echo "<br/>";
            }
            foreach ($elements2 as $el2) {
                echo $el2->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
                echo "<br/>";
            }       
    }
    echo "<hr>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the **Procedure**:

1. Read the directory using [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)
2. Then read all `html files` by using [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) Refer
   [How to list files and folder in a dir (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050511/how-to-list-files-and-folder-in-a-dir-php)
3. Use [get_meta_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) to get `meta tags` and `for title` refer [How can I get the title of an HTML page using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914573/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-an-html-page-using-php) same code used for **body** you need to change `preg_match` condition. You can **try this too** [Getting title and meta tags from external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site)

Try the above points and you get some success in it. Then come with a new `question`